# How to vectorize (OR speed up) the following (numpy / pandas) code which needs to fill values conditional on last appended value?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I want to append `'Y'` or `'N'` to a `list / numpy array / pandas series` called `x` with varying probability (*e.g. probability of 'Y' again given the last element was 'Y' is 0.8, else 0.5 if the last element was 'N'*). This is done using `np.random.choice`. I want to do this 100,000 times. I have written a `for` loop for this but I am not sure if this is the fastest / most efficient way.

```
# choose 'Y' or 'N' at random for first element
x = [np.random.choice(a = ['Y', 'N'])]

for i in range(10**6):
    # append 'Y' or 'N' with probability dependent on x[-1] being 'Y' or 'N'
    x.append(np.random.choice(a = ['Y', 'N'], p = [0.8, 0.2]) if x[-1] == 'Y' else np.random.choice(a = ['Y', 'N'], p = [0.5, 0.5]))
```

I guess maybe `numpy select / where` in conjunction with `pandas shift / numpy roll` method may help but don't know how (because of dependence on last element / above row complicates the vectorization)

Any help to speed up the code would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a simulation or you just need and array with that distribution? Reason for the question is: The problem is sequential in nature, let's say someone comes up with some clever trick to generate an array with the expected distribution without actually performing sequential sampling. Then, you would get the "expected" output of the experiment (hypothesis), without actually performing it, which would invalidate it as a proper simulation experiment.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly this is a simulation. Theoretically, the frequency density of 'Y' is 5/7 = 0.714 but I also want to see this through simulation.

Comment: `select/where` are NOT iterators.  You give them whole evluated arrays or Series, and they pick values from those.  Sounds like your problem is inherently serial in nature - evaluate row `i` based on values in row `i-1`.  You can't do that in a parallel, 'vectorized' fashion.  The only sequential kind of operations in `numpy` are things like `cumsum`

Answer (score 0):

You can get a slight improvement by using

```
x.append(np.random.choice(a = ['Y', 'N'], p = [0.8, 0.2]) if x[-1] == 'Y' else np.random.choice(a = ['Y', 'N']))
```

without setting the probabilities for the case when the previous choice was 'N'. From the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

> Setting user-specified probabilities through p uses a more general but less efficient sampler than the default. The general sampler produces a different sample than the optimized sampler even if each element of p is 1 / len(a).

My suggested solution would be to sample first the cases were previous choice *was* not 'N' (without actually looking at the previous choice, since it hasn't happened yet) and then "correct" for previous 'Y':

```
# choose Y or N with p = [0.5, 0.5]
x = np.random.choice(a = ['Y', 'N'], size=10**6)

for i in range(1, 10**6):
    # if x[-1] == 'Y' choose 'Y' or 'N' with p = [0.8, 0.2]
    if x[-1] == 'Y':
        x[i] = np.random.choice(a = ['Y', 'N'], p = [0.8, 0.2])
    # if x[-1] == 'N' keep the actual value, chosen with p = [0.5, 0.5]
    else: pass
```

With `%%timeit` I get 304 ms per loop (best of 5) vs 21.3 s per loop in the original code (but a warning that "The slowest run took 74.03 times longer than the fastest")

With `%%time`, results are variable every time I run the cells, but consistently faster using this version (last one got 427 ms total CPU time vs 23.4 s).

Comment: I'm a bit newbie at programming, so any advice on how to do a better benchmarking will be highly appreciated!

Comment: the code that would fulfill my requirement (in your way) needs to have `x[i] = np.random.choice(a = ['Y', 'N'], p = [0.5, 0.5])` in `else`.
In that case `%%time` gives me 21.1s, so not much of an improvement. Also, I believe Python's `timeit` module allows to do better benchmarking - https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html

Comment: The idea here is that  `else: x[i] = np.random.choice(a = ['Y', 'N'], p = [0.5, 0.5])` was previously done when the original array was generated. So, there's no need to run it again.